# Select different word each time TAB key is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-shortcuts

Move across each word in a sentences.

I have created shortcut key for enter in my application as, it will move towards and focus each input control in my page.

I need to set keyboard shortcuts for tab as, it has to select each string of a sentences which are in some textbox. For example txtAddress contain value like "Hi i am new user", if I press tab key it has to select a string "hi" then "i" then "am" then "new" then "user" after that it has to focus a next input control.

I have tried with following JS to focus next input control but don't know how to select each word in textbox.

```
$(document).unbind('keydown');
$(document).bind('keydown', 'tab', function assets() {
    try {
        var inputs = $(":input:not(input[type='hidden'])");
        var CurInput = inputs.get(inputs.index(document.activeElement));
        var nextInput = inputs.get(inputs.index(document.activeElement) + 1);
        if (CurInput && nextInput.type == "text" && CurInput.style.display != "none") {
            var strval = CurInput.value;
            if (!strval) {
                if (nextInput && nextInput.type != "hidden" && nextInput.style.display != "none") {
                    nextInput.focus();
                }
            }
        }
        else if (nextInput && nextInput.type != "hidden" && nextInput.style.display != "none") {
            nextInput.focus();
        }
        return false;
    }
    catch (e) {
    }
});
```

Comment: I've never seen this syntax. `'shift+tab'`??? what is that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/cihahigevo/1/edit?html,js,output

```
var textarea = $('textarea')[0],
    index = 0;

$(document).on('keydown.tab', function(e){
  if( e.keyCode == 9 ){
    textarea.focus();
    textarea.value = textarea.value.trim() + ' ';
    index = textarea.value.indexOf(' ', index) + 1;
    textarea.setSelectionRange(0, index);
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: actually i have captured tab key. What i need is select each word in textbox while pressing tab key

Comment: so use `this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);` where `this` is the textbox element

Comment: yes but i have select each word dynamically not whole textbox value

Comment: Thanks i have changed it by `textarea.setSelectionRange(index, index);`. Now its working

Answer (score 0):

It's never a good idea to override a users keyboard, especially the tab button.

The tab button is used by people who (for whatever reason) don't use a mouse to navigate sites by 'tabbing' between buttons, form fields, etc.

If you remove this functionality by overriding the tab key, you've suddenly made your site unaccessible to these users.

You may also run afoul of you countries laws on website accessibility (the Disability & Discrimation act in the UK).

Comment: actually i have captured tab key. What i need is select each word in textbox while pressing tab key